# Angular Single Page Application fetching data from server every time it goes to a new Route

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-router

My simple Angular Single Page application has two components. I have defined a route for each of these components. If I click on a link, corresponding component should be displayed in the view.

## Router

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CompAComponent } from './comp-a/comp-a.component';
import { CompBComponent } from './comp-b/comp-b.component';
 
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'componentA', component: CompAComponent
  },{
    path: 'componentB', component: CompBComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

## HTML

```html
<div class="main-container">
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="testApp/componentA">componentA</a></li>
        <li><a href="testApp/componentB">componentB</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="component-container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

</div>
```

## App.Module

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CompAComponent } from './comp-a/comp-a.component';
import { CompBComponent } from './comp-b/comp-b.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CompAComponent,
    CompBComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This application is working but every time I click on a link, it is fetching all the JS files from the server. Shouldn't a single page application get all the required files from server during initial loading?

I added 'testApp' in the href since this application has a context path of 'textApp' in the head of index.html file like `<base href="/testApp">`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular needs to do some stuff behind the scenes to tell the browser how to handle links within the SPA. So you should use the attribute `routerLink` on your links instead of `href` so Angular knows which links are SPA-links.

```html
<div class="main-container">
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul>
        <li><a routerLink="/componentA">componentA</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/componentB">componentB</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="component-container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

</div>
```

More info: https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial#control-navigation-with-ui-elements